# C# - Kerosene ORM - Can't find the default engine and the connection string

Tags: c#, mysql, orm

I am new to the C#/.NET world and I am currently trying to developp a C# application using Kerosene ORM to link it to my MySQL Database. It's a local Database hosted thanks to WAMP.

To initiate a connection to the database via KeroseneORM I need to provide the engine name and a connection string.

What is the engine name ? In the Kerosene code it's described like this :

```
/// <param name="name">A string containing either the invariant name of the engine, or
/// its tail part, or the name of a connection string entry in the configuration files,
/// or null. In the later case, the name of the default connection string entry is used.</param>
```

I don't know what the "engine" is so I tried to add a connection string entry in the App.config file like this :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="LocalDB"
     providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
     connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=bms;Uid=root;Pwd=root;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

But it rise an exception that say "Cannot find a 'LocalDB' registered engine."

So basically, what is an "engine" and how can I provide it to Kerosene ?
I know this may be a stupid question but I can't find any answer on the internet and Kerosene is really not well-documented.

Secondly, I know my connection string is wrong, because the Server name is not the correct one, but I can't find the right one. So does anyone know what is the Server name when using WAMP on your local machine ? I tried things like "127.0.0.1" or "localhost\mysql_wampserver" but nothing works.

Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad english (not my native language).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app.config must have this section:

```
 <keroseneORM>
    <customEngines>
      <add id="SqlServer2008"     type="Kerosene.ORM.SqlServer.v2008.Concrete.DataEngine" assembly="Kerosene.ORM.SqlServer.dll" />
      <add id="SqlServer2012" type="Kerosene.ORM.SqlServer.v2012.Concrete.DataEngine" assembly="Kerosene.ORM.SqlServer.dll" />
    </customEngines>
    <dataLink connectionString="LocalDB" />
  </keroseneORM>
```

Comment: Thanks ! Even if I already got the information since, that's a correct answer !